# Is there a way to make find projection support operators, as I would with $project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

*I should first point out I am not attacking Mongo here. I like Mongo. Mongo is cool.*

If I have data like this:

```
{
  a: 2,
  b: 2
},
{
  a:3,
  b:4
}
```

I can use aggregation with $project to format the results:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    c: {
      $add: ["$a", "$b"]
    }
  }
})
```

which will yield

```
{
  c: 4
},
{
  c:7
}
```

I notice the find function also supports projection as a second argument. However if I do this:

```
db.collection.find({}, {
  c: {
    $add: ["$a", "$b"]
  }
});
```

The query fails.

Can I enable expression based projection in find, and if not, is this by accident or design, or my own dimwittery?

Comment: I think you don't understand how projection works with `find`. The projection document limits the fields to return for all matching documents. The projection document can specify the inclusion of fields or the exclusion of fields. But the `$project` stage in aggregation allow you to perform additional operation because we are aggregating data not trying to find document.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of how projection works with find, it's toothless, and inconsistent but presumably under the hood it is hitting the same stack as $project. I'm querying whether or not the inconsistency is real, or only apparent.

Comment: Gosh, the mongo crowd are hostile. I'm not attacking Mongo here. Why all the downvotes? It's a reasonable question?

Answer (score 2):

The projection inside `find` and `$project` work differently. As you may find in the documentation, the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) is defined for and under the aggregation framework.

By the way, another difference is that for example, in `find` projection you can exclude fields using the `{field: 0}` notation, but that is not possible in the aggregation pipeline `$project`.